# Firebase getting string value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I uploaded string values to realtime database of Firebase but I couldn't get it back. I put breakpoint and observed that it doesn't get into listener. I need help, what im doing wrong?

[image: Firebase]

The code I upload string values:

```
    DatabaseReference user_details = mDatabaseIns.getReference("storeIDs"); 
    String photoID = user_details.push().getKey(); // get unique key
    user_details.child(photoID).setValue(image_id); // upload value to unique key
```

The code I get string values (it doesn't print anything to console):

```
    public void getImageNames() {
        DatabaseReference userPhotoIdsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("storeIDs");
        userPhotoIdsRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot uniqueKeySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.i("RECORDSFRAGMENT", dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));

                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: try `uniqueKeySnapshot.getValue(String.class)`

Comment: are you trying to print out all the values in the `storeIDs`?

Comment: yes, I want to do this for now. I will store them in array later. by the way `uniqueKeySnapshot.getValue(String.class)` didn't work.

Comment: I didn't understand. After multiple trials it worked. I think I have problem in my whole class code. I will ask it in another question. Thank you @PeterHaddad for solution.

Comment: As Peter pointed out, you're using the wrong variable name: `Log.i("RECORDSFRAGMENT", dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));` should be `Log.i("RECORDSFRAGMENT", uniqueSnapshot.getValue(String.class));`.